# How to call jpa repository inside a method with @Scheduled?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Whenever I call a repository inside a method with @Scheduled, I am always getting this error: `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."` I tried to remove @Scheduled and call the service manually and its working. Already tried to put @Transactional on the method same result. I tried to separate the @Transactional to a different class but still same error. Any ideas?

Edit:
This is the sample code pretty simple actually. I just edit the name of the class for privacy

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {

    @Autowired
    SampleRepo sampleRepo;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    @Override
    public void send() {

        List<User> users = Lists.newArrayList(sampleRepo.findAll());
    }
}
```

This is the logs:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1275) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getResultList(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:254) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.SP1.jar:4.2.7.SP1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:330) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:405) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:390) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 743
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
```

Comment: what's postgresql version?

Comment: At first glance, this error is more related with SQL syntax, rather than with @Scheduled. Could you post some code?

Comment: @user7294900 postgres version is 9.5.7

Comment: Can you test with version 9.4.1211?

Comment: yeah but I need to make it work with my current version.

Comment: post complete logs..with this single it is difficult to understand the issue

Comment: call `sampleRepo.someCall()`

Comment: It would be better if you provide a github link for your code.

Comment: Can you post your repository.. ?

Comment: Post the SQL that leads to the error.